# Not able to load partials in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, projects-and-solutions

I am new in angular js and trying to load a view(jsp) using angular route. I have set up a vanilla project and trying to run it on server. Though my application home page is perfectly loading but I am not able to load a different view using angular route. When I am debugging it using developer's tool it is showing a page not found error.

**Error seen on developer's tool**

[image: Error seen on developer's tool]

**Project Setup**

[image: Project Setup]

it seems I have messed up with project set up.Any help will be truly appreciable

Comment: If you browse to the .jsp manually in the browser is it returned as expected?

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl is relative to app folder in angular. 
In your case, it should be:

```
templateUrl: 'views/applicationLogin/login.jsp'
```

and so on. 
Because i see that you have views folder in WEB-INF folder, as index.jsp ought to reside there.

Another case, that haven't been trying jsps instead of html, don't know if that would work.